# Personal cgi-bin folder forbidden

Tags: cgi-bin, lampp

It's my first post and please, keep calm, i'm noob with lampp.

My problem, that i've searched for 2 days in many pages, is this:

I'd create a new virtualhost in htdocs lampp, its two folders:

cgi-bin and html.

My problem is Object not found! 404 error when i try to submit a form wich action to /cgi-bin/x.cgi

It's no problem when i enter into html thats takes me to index.html.

If I try to enter directly to cgi-bin from localhost it shoots me Access forbidden! 403 error.

This is my virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/formvalidation/"
        ServerName my-serv.com
        <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/formvalidation/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/formvalidation/html/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/formvalidation/cgi-bin">
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,In$
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If anybody could help me...

Thank you so much.